# Flink streaming - Change part file names when using StreamingFileSink?

Tags: java, apache-flink, avro, parquet

I'm trying to use Flink streaming for consuming Kafka topic messages and create (periodically) parquet files that will be saved on s3.
Is there a way when using streaming file sink with bulk format to change part file names created (or adding suffix/prefix) to be more unique than part-0-0 or part-1-3 ?

```
StreamingFileSink<> sink = StreamingFileSink.forBulkFormat(new Path("s3://test-bucket/"),               ParquetAvroFactory.getParquetWriter(schema,  CompressionCodec.UNCOMPRESSED.name()))
.withBucketAssigner(new PartitionBucketAssigner(partitionColumns))
.build();
```

Comment: How was your implementation of `ParquetAvroFactory` ?

Comment: did u find any solution for this? I am looking for the same and how to avoid overwriting my files in s3 when restarting my application with checkpoint?

Comment: if you are restarting from a checkpoint you shouldn't have a problem since the file would contain a suffix of the checkpoint sequence number.
Anyhow Flink would have a solution for part file name in version 1.10

Answer (score 0):

You can override the getBucketId method (see https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/sink/filesystem/BucketAssigner.html) on the BucketAssigner, which will affect the path, but apparently not the part file names (see the comment below).

The part file names are established in this bit of code in `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket`:

```
private Path assembleNewPartPath() {
    return new Path(bucketPath, PART_PREFIX + '-' + subtaskIndex + '-' + partCounter);
}
```

which does not appear to be designed to be customized.

Comment: tried it, it changes only the sub directories the files will be written to, not the file name itself

Comment: how can i avoid overwriting my files in s3 when restarting my application with checkpoint?

Comment: @YitzchakLieberman if you are restarting from a "savepoint" you will not overwrite the files. If you are starting afresh, you will overwrite files.